How to build Flutter application (Android) from android studio terminal?
After setting flavors in app level, build.gradle file,run with
flutter build apk --flavor uat -t /lib/main_uat.dart command in android studio terminal. I got below error.But I can run flutter doctor and flutter run command from terminal.
Could not find an option or flag "-t".


Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.

But set configuration and run from android studio UI button is work. Why this happen? To run from android studio terminal how can I fix that?

I found answer myself. I forgot to add --release flag as suffix like that.
Now I fixed as
flutter build apk --flavor uat -t lib/main_uat.dart --release and it generate apk.
